# Inner Join not returning values?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to solve an Inner Join problem on PG Exercises.
Link to problem-
https://pgexercises.com/questions/joins/simplejoin2.html

Problem is:

How can you produce a list of the start times for bookings for tennis courts, for the date '2012-09-21'? Return a list of start time and facility name pairings, ordered by the time.

Schema:
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhlCA.png

My code is :

```
SELECT starttime,name
FROM cd.bookings
INNER JOIN cd.facilities ON cd.bookings.facid = cd.facilities.facid
WHERE cd.bookings.starttime >='2012-09-21'
AND  cd.bookings.starttime < '2012-09-22'
AND  cd.facilities.name LIKE 'tennis%';
```

Solution code is :

```
select bks.starttime as start, 
       facs.name as name
from cd.facilities facs
inner join cd.bookings bks on facs.facid = bks.facid
where  facs.name in ('Tennis Court 2','Tennis Court 1') 
and bks.starttime >= '2012-09-21' 
and bks.starttime < '2012-09-22'
order by bks.starttime;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions. (Without more information, I can't see how the given solution is right or not.)

Comment: @jarlh, it seems to be postgres db. Visit the link in the question. ;)

Comment: @MaciejLos, I rarely never follow links. A question here is supposed to be self-contained.

Comment: @jarlh, Agree! We have to have more patient to new conributors and sometimes help them to improve thier questions by visiting link (what i'm gonna do).

Comment: @MaciejLos, and asking for a mcve and the dbms is my way to educate new users. (Instead of downvoting.)

Comment: @jarlh Sorry about that. New to stackoverflow and still getting used to formatting everything. Thank you for the recommendations.

Comment: @MaciejLos Thank you for your help! I really appreciate your patience. I am new to S.O and still getting used to the system.

Comment: @LarchPhi7, no problem at all. We are all here to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is here:

```
facilities.name LIKE 'tennis%'
```

[`LIKE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) is [case sensitive](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitivity).

Specify the correct case:

```
facilities.name LIKE 'Tennis%'
```

Or use `ILIKE`, which is the case *insensitive* variant of `LIKE`:

```
facilities.name ILIKE 'tennis%'
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you. Can't believe it was due to being case sensitive.

Comment: @LarchPhi7 case sensitive is the SQL standard, but MySQL doesn’t always follow the standard: MySQL’s `LIKE` is case *insensitive*, so if you’ve used MySQL before, that could be a source of confusion/frustration.

Comment: Case sensitive or not depends on the column collation.